# A word meaning more than "like", but less than "love"

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, synonyms

I'm sure there must be a word that fits the bill; "like a lot" and "fond" don't really cut.  Any suggestions welcomed.

Comment: Why, "*loke*", of course.

Comment: A trendy word among teens today is "heart" used as a verb:  *I heart you.*  which derives from a literal reading the bumper stickers that replace the word love with a red heart.

Comment: @Jim it is? Ugh! Where do these teens live? What part of the world?

Comment: @terdon- All over the US.  One lives in my house.

Comment: @Jim  I thought they lived on their smartphones. When I had a teenager, they lived at the mall. The good news is that they don't stay teens forever.  The bad news is that when they marry, one doesn't gain a daughter and grandchildren, one loses a son.

Comment: "Adore" is perfect for that awkward "Well, I like him a lot, but I'm not ready to say I love him" phase.

Comment: There are lots of different terms folks use in an attempt to express this ambiguous degree of affection.  But it is inherently a "squishy" problem, since usually the intent is to avoid being nailed down.

Answer (score 2):

***Fond*** can be considered as more than like and less than love. (Used as *be fond of*)

> Having a **strong liking**, inclination, or affection: fond of ballet; fond of my nieces and nephews.
>
> <sup>http://www.thefreedictionary.com/fond</sup>

Though, it might depend on the context and it can be synonymous to *like* also. It is usually not used in a romantic relationship and you can both love and be fond of someone. For example, you can both love your niece and be fond of him because you like to spend time with him.

Other than that, ***infatuation*** can be considered as an early stage of a true love (used as  *infatuated with*) but it is not necessarily between like and love. It is called *puppy love* also.

For example, an [urbandictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=infatuation) entry says:

> Infatuation consists of people thinking they are in love but when indeed it is just a deep lust or like for another person.

Also, ***attraction*** can be stronger than like and weaker than love. (used as *attracted to*). Though it is usually a physical attraction and you can be attracted to someone you don't like. (an emotional irony?)

In the end, it might be better to use several words to explain the emotion than using a single word that might not be enough. There are different situations and contexts.

Comment: How can the first suggestion here be considered to answer OP when '"fond" [doesn't] really cut' is explicitly stated, even before the edit? (Although it's the word I'd use, too.)

Comment: Why not "affection" itself? To me the word seems to fit the space between"like" and "love"

Answer (score 1):

If it has to be more casual and superficial - what about "FANCY".

Answer (score 1):

Admire, respect, care for, desire, lust, fancy, am charmed by, appreciate. Pick one of these words and look in a thesaurus.

Comment: "stalk" made me laugh :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm fond of "fond". One, because it's a not an everyday word, it does have a little more strength, a little more intimacy than "like". However, it can be, but is not necessarily, romantic. You can be fond of people you love and you can be fond of your friends.

"I fancy you" is too cordial. Besides, if you're in America, it sounds so foreign that it's almost tongue-in-cheek. "I'm fond of you" is not so stilted. It's a very warm word, suited to many scenarios.